# re connecting a capacitor to a single phase fan motor

Tags: capacitor

Firstly please forgive my ignorance but at 80+ I find it difficult to follow  some of the technical jargon as this field evolves.
I am trying to repair an industrial fan motor to be used as a blower for a clay furnace.
The motor type is: PBL20093-EM10135, Single Phase,  8mFD, 240V, 250W .
The capacitor was missing so I have no previous knowledge of it's wiring.
There are four wires coming from the motor including an earth which is prominantly marked green and yellow, the remainder are red, blue and white, the readings from these are  Red/Blue 80 Ohms, Red/White 71 Ohms and Blue/White 33 Ohms, I find this confusing for a start as I would expect the cobination of the second and third pairs to be eaqual to the sum of the first, maybe there is a reason for this that I'm not awere, If you could enlighten me that would be a great help.
The information I have been following sugests the red/blue wirescapacitor should be connected to one side of the capacitor, the white to the neutral Vin. but I get lost trying to follow the circuit from there on. Some sugestions seem quite alien and some instructions apere to be truncated and bits missed out and I am unable to guess the correct route to follow, I have managed to get the motor running but it has to be turned manualy to start it running and that is not satisfactory
I have searched the historicle notes here relating to this subgect but unable to find anything that closely relates to my problem.
I would be most grateful for any assistances
Thanking you in advance
Fred

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies  if question is a bit vague, I need to connect a capacitor to a FAN moptor .

Comment: my apologies if my request is vague. I am trying to re-place a non existing capacitor to an industrial fan motor, the name plate shows thay it requires an (Eight) 8uFD cap..